# Does Stack Overflow have plans to make runnable code snippets for the Android app?

Tags: support, stack-snippets, android-app

The **Stack snippets** is the best way to demonstrate problem in question post and provide runnable solution in an answer. But this tools doesn't work in the Official Stack Overflow application for Android devices.
I know it is possible to open post in a browser to run or edit snippet. I also understand the implementation of the feature requires to develop special GUI that will consider small screen size. But I have two questions: are there plans to make Stack Snippets

1. runnable
2. editable

for the Android application? It would be great even if the only first point will be implemented.

Comment: I think it's a bit impractical for such a small screen no? Plus there are currently zero people working on the Android app, and the iOS app doesn't have snippets either yet.

Comment: @AndrewLi, I don't know how many peoples use Android App, but I use it very often. And often it is difficult to understand a trouble if the code snippet from question isn't runnable. Moreover runnable code snippets helps to exclude mistakes while answer. It is not so conveniently as at desktop, but doing this with a third-party app is even worse. I has installed Stack Exchange Application to work at it, but I have to use browser instead.

Comment: I use the iOS 90% of the time because I'm usually far away from a desktop. I just don't use snippets. And by working on I mean developing

Comment: @Makoto, be careful, the question that you mention about mobile version of Stack Overflow. My question about Official Stack Overflow application (see tags).

Comment: Oh.  I would argue though that you're going to find yourself in the same fix since the Stack Overflow application is effectively in permanent maintenance mode now.